DocumentAI OCR Error: Invalid Document Content
I am calling DocumentAI OCR batch processing from Workflows generally quite successfully, however, I occasionally get the following error:
{
  "caughtError": {
    "message": "An error occurred during execution of a long-running operation.",
    "operation": {
      "done": true,
      "error": {
        "code": 3,
        "message": "Failed to process all documents."
      },
      "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.documentai.v1.BatchProcessMetadata",
        "createTime": "2024-07-18T12:43:54.456405Z",
        "individualProcessStatuses": [
          {
            "inputGcsSource": "gs://redacted_bucket_name/redacted.pdf",
            "status": {
              "code": 3,
              "message": "Invalid input document content."
            }
          }
        ],
        "state": "FAILED",
        "updateTime": "2024-07-18T12:44:25.393457Z"
      },
      "name": "projects/###/locations/us/operations/###"
    },
    "tags": [
      "OperationError"
    ]
  }

I am able to isolate the error down to the page by breaking the pdf up to see which page is causing the error. However, I am unable to discern what the exact cause of the error is programmatically to fix it.
I am able to use libraries like pypdf and pymupdf to open the pdf and successfully extract the text (if it exists). I have also tried using pymupdf to compress the pdf using various compression settings, and I am able to compress the pdf, but this does not prevent the error. On one pdf where I was encountering the issue, setting enableNativePdfParsing to false allowed the pdf to process, however this does not prevent the error in all cases I am seeing.
Is there some way I can preprocess my pdfs to ensure the pdf is compatible with DocumentAI or is there another way to solve this issue?

I don't have much insight but it sure seems like the PDF contains invalid content. When you identify the specific page with the error(s), is the Document AI reproducible? Are you able to further binary chop the single page into two until your narrow the issue further?
